# configuring apache2 to make respond a web2py specific application to a secondary hostname

Tags: web, configuration, apache2, virtualhost, web2py

Let's say I have a server and I have set up on my host name provider a record A to assign the server IP to an address such as main.mycompany.com. Following the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#Linux-and-Unix) of the adopted web framework (web2py) I set up apache2 in mod_wsgi mode in order to let web2py answare the requests of the main address so now **main.mycompany.com** is redirected to main.mycompany.com/welcome/default/home.html and all installed applications are correcly reachable with such an address like main.mycompany.com/myapp.

Now I set up on my host name provider even a record CNAME **secondary.mycompany.com** that points to **main.mycompany.com** and I would like to set up a new virtualhost so that all requests to **secondary.mycompany.com** are served by a specific web2py application (myapp).
In this way calling main.mycompany.com/myapp would have tha same result as secondary.mycompany.com.

What would be a configuration that fits my needs?

Thankyou very mutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that can be sorted using routes.py in the web2py folder.  Not sure you *need* a second virtual host, but that's the way I've done it with NGINX.

```
routers = dict(
    BASE  = dict(
        domains = {'secondary.mycompany.com': 'myapp'},                
        exclusive_domain = True,  # No other application can be accessed from this subdomain
    ),
)
```